# KEYS с пробелами в Redis

Tags: redis, key, nosql

Как обратится к значению по ключу с пробелами в cli режиме?

```
get field with spaces
get "field with spaces"
get 'field with spaces'
```

Эти варианты дают ошибку:

```
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В результате пришлось сделать ssh доступ к серверу и использую программу redis-cli обращаться к этим ключам примерно следующим образом:

```
redis-cli get 'key with spaces'
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя ключи с пробелами использовать в Redis.

> **Redis keys**
>
> Before to start talking
> about the different kind of values
> supported by Redis it is better to
> start saying that keys are not binary
> safe strings in Redis, but just
> strings not containing a space or a
> newline character. For instance "foo"
> or "123456789" or "foo_bar" are valid
> keys, while "hello world" or "hello\n"
> are not.
>
> http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro

*Вольный перевод:*

Перед тем, как говорить о разных видах значений, поддерживаемых Редис, необходимо сначала сказать, что ключом может быть не любая строка, а только строка, которая не содержат символ пробела или перевода строки. К примеру, строки "foo" или "123456789" или "foo_bar" могут быть использованы в качестве ключа, в то же время строки "hello world" или "hello\n" нет.

Comment: А как же я через апи писал и получал эти значения по ключу с пробелами??

Comment: Возможно их API просто производит urlencode на ключе перед операцией get/set. То есть, пробел будет заменен %20 и все пройдет.